# I can't get the text from a span using javascript and vue.js for one truncate

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I wanto create a truncate with a buttom for more info in vue.js and javascript but when I get the values with javascript it send me null, I been checking and the way I make the reques it is correct this how got the code:

html:

```
   <div class="col-lg-10 ">
        <span>{{video.description}}</span>
        <button type="button" id="info" name="button">more inf...</button>
   </div>
```

vue.js

```
export default {
 mounted(){
       var lengthText = 90;
//Aqui en la variable text guardas el texto antes de ocultarlo
var text = $('span').text();
var shortText = $.trim(text).substring(0, lengthText).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";
console.log(text);
console.log(shortText);
$('span').text(shortText);
//entonces para mostrarlo nuevamente solo necesitas mostrar la variable text
$('button').click(function(event) {
  $('span').text(text);
});
  }
}
```

[image]
it doesn't make the truncate or the action in the buttom I will really appreciatte i you can help me with this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're totally missing the point of Vue. Barring a few special cases (mostly with third-party plugins that rely on jQuery to use), seeing jQuery code in a Vue component means you're doing something *wrong*.

Here's a rewrite that uses Vue's functionality to accomplish your goal:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 ">
    <span v-if="showMoreInfo">{{ description }}</span>
    <span v-else>{{ shortDescription }}</span>

    <button v-if="!showMoreInfo" @click="moreInfo">more info...</button>
</div>

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            description: 'This is my long, long description.',
            showMoreInfo: false,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        shortDescription: function() {
            // you're free to do something more complex here
            // for illustration purposes, we're just trimming
            // the string down to size
            return this.description.substring(0, 90);
        }
    },
    methods: {
        moreInfo: function() {
            this.showMoreInfo = true;
        }
    }
}
```

No jQuery required, and far more readable too.